# grunt-include-replace adding a folder when it compiles

Tags: html, gruntjs, grunt-includes

I'm about at my wits end trying to figure this out. I have the include replace pulling from a src folder and compiling into a dist folder. It is doing that, however, it's adding a src folder into the dist folder and putting the html file into that. If I pull from the root directory instead of the src folder, it works just fine and puts just the html into the dist folder with no extra folder. Why would adding the path into the src folder create another src folder inside the dist folder and how would I get it to stop doing that?

My code is set up like this...

```
    distdir: 'dist',
    srcdir: 'src',
    includereplace: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                includesDir: '<%= srcdir %>/includes/'
            },
            src: '<%= srcdir %>/*.html',
            dest: '<%= distdir %>'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I figured it out. I have to do this:

```
files: [
    {
        src: '*.html',
        dest: '<%= distdir %>/',
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= srcdir %>/'
    }
]
```